# How to fetch constantly changing value on a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to get the changing price of some stock on a website, without sending
requests.get() again and again using beautifulsoup.

Comment: Well, does the data source offer any alternative…?

Comment: `without sending requests.get()`? Then how do you expect to reach the website? BeautifulSoup is simply an HTML parser.

Comment: can it be done with selinium?

Comment: *Probably*, but what advantage would that give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have mentioned selenium, yes it can also be done using `refresh()` instead of `get()`.

Run `driver.navigate().refresh();` after a specific amount of time to refresh the page and `driver.findElement()` to pull the data from the page again.

But there is no fundamental difference in using `requests.get()` and `refresh()` because both will just tell the browser to repeat the GET or POST request, except the in case of if it has an [Expires Header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are forced to read the html representation, you will probably have no choice, but to periodically pull the website.

Comment: what do u mean by html representation

Comment: You query the website and then parse it's html code to find some value. If there is no other interface to the website (eg get the data by long pulling, ...), you are forced to pull the website periodically.